# Text to array. Strange empty line in results

Tags: php

I have problem change text into array

This is text in file:

```
 zkyu,team 3
 primesteval,team 2
 graves,team 3
```

My snipped;

```
$file = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$members = array();
$toMoveMem = array();

$i = 0;
while (!feof($fh))
{
 $members[] = fgets($fh);   
}
fclose($fh);
foreach ($members as $Mem)
{
$MemS = explode(",", $Mem);
$a = ($MemS[0]);
$b = ($MemS[1]);
$c = str_replace("team", "", $b);
array_push($toMoveMem, array("MemberNick" => $a, "MemberTeam" => $c));
}
```

Problem is the strange empty line in array keys 0 and 1:

```
   Array
    (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [MemberNick] => zkyu
        [MemberTeam] =>  3

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [MemberNick] => primesteval
        [MemberTeam] =>  2

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [MemberNick] => graves
        [MemberTeam] =>  3
    )

    )
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Why array key 1 and 2 dont look like array key 3?

Can someone help me and explain.

Comment: What am I missing here? I don't see `the strange empty line in array keys 0 and 1`. The three arrays look identical to me...

Comment: Before the closing `)` for each item.

Comment: Yup there it is - I see it now. Thanks @dcclassics +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting it's because there's a newline after the first two objects.  The third doesn't have one after it because it's the end of the file.  You can use `trim()` on the `$c`.

`$c = trim(str_replace("team", "", $b));`

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as a solution if you're satisfied. :)

Comment: Glad that I could help.